# Use https for img src

Tags: https, images

My site requires the use of https for all img src HTML.

This is the WordPress function I'm using to display images:

```
<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/thumb-default.gif" />
```

This outputs an http img src - how can I convert that to https?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress checks the return value of `is_ssl()` before creating URLs using `get_bloginfo()`.  If the function returns true, it creates https URLs.  If it returns false, it creates http URLs.

From the WordPress source ...

```
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )
            return true;
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
            return true;
    } elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So ... if the request was made over https or if the request came in over port 443, then `get_bloginfo()` will return an `https://` URL.  In reality, if you're forcing https anyway, you should force all requests to port 80 (http) over to port 443 (https) ... but that's a server configuration issue, not a WordPress issue.

Alternatively, you could hook into a filter and replace http with https ...

Just use:

```
function replace_http( $original ) {
    // use preg_replace() to replace http:// with https://
    $output = preg_replace( "^http:", "https:", $original );
    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'template_url', 'replace_http' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you checked this when requesting page via `http` or `https` link? What does [`is_ssl()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) return for you?

I don't have SSL-capable stack to test at moment, but I am pretty sure that WP functions that put together links should be aware of SSL and output correct version.

Comment: The page URL in my browser is https, but the img src links are http.

Comment: @Ryan this is not normal behavior, I've checked and it should be https link generated in such case... see EAMann's answer for extended details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) function will automatically detect ssl and change protocols.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the fix proposed by EAMann I have made some changes for version 3.5:

```
add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', function( $original ) {
    $output = preg_replace( "/^http:/i", "https:", $original );
    return $output;
});
```

I'd like to note that this redirect thing may be very helpful, but my server redirects SSL to another port and is not detected by WP so for me it's an annoyance.

Comment: Are you referring to WordPress 3.5? Is so, that's great!